# How shuold use yield in pthread()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu

For example I am doing active hyper-threading in my system, two threads are running in each core.

Now my question is:

When one of these thread calls `yield()` what happens?

This is true in such situation use `yield()`.

Comment: Why not follow the actual documentation, what's unclear in particular?

Comment: my question is what happen in this situation?

Comment: Again, what's actually unclear for you from here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html ??

Comment: this:pthread_yield() causes the calling thread to relinquish the CPU.

Comment: when i assign each thread to each core how it can possible?

Comment: Relinquish means the thread actively goes to suspended mode.

Comment: You shouldn't suspend a thread that yields. It should remain ready to run.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some unusual special requirements, when a thread calls `yield()` you should switch to another ready-to-run thread and leave the yielding thread ready-to-run. Which ready-to-run thread to switch to, if there is more than one, is up to you. You could prefer a thread assigned to that core but you could also do "thread stealing" if you want.